# find many to many with no relation

Tags: mysql, sql, database, many-to-many

I have an `items` table, a `tags` table and a `reletations` table.
I need to find untagged items.

With this (working) query I find the tags number for each item:

```
SELECT i.id, i.text, COUNT( ti.item ) AS count
FROM items AS i
JOIN topic_item AS ti ON ti.item = i.id
GROUP BY ti.item
```

If tried to modify the query with:

```
ti.item != i.id
```

or I add

```
WHERE count = 0
```

But it's not the right way.
Which is the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `left join`, and get the items where there is no matching tag:

```
SELECT i.id, i.text
FROM items AS i
LEFT JOIN topic_item AS ti ON ti.item = i.id
WHERE ti.item is null
```

You can also use `not exists`:

```
SELECT i.id, i.text
FROM items AS i
WHERE not exists(
  select * from topic_item AS ti
  where ti.item = i.id
)
```

Comment: The first query's result shows only the first row, the second one works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @WalterVilla: When I test the first query I get all rows where there is no topic: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6aec4/1

Answer (score 1):

Try `left join` as below

```
SELECT i.id, i.text, COUNT( ti.item ) AS count
FROM items AS i
LEFT JOIN topic_item AS ti ON ti.item = i.id
WHERE ti.item is null
GROUP BY ti.item
```

Comment: The result shows only the first row. In my case it's ok.